# Where to find Generic.xaml for native WPF controls?

Tags: wpf, styles

Where to find Generic.xaml (or other code with the default look) for native WPF controls such as Button, CheckBox, TextBox, etc?

Comment: The easiest way, to me so far, is to use Blend, as Martin suggests. Drop the control onto a Window, right-click on it, select Edit Template -- Edit a Copy, give the new style a name and voila.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Silverlight (and I know that your question is about WPF) this information is more accessible than in WPF. You can get this information from any of these sources:

1. [Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278075(VS.95).aspx) on MSDN.
2. You can look at the resources of the relevant Silverlight assembly and extract the `themes/generic.xaml` embedded in a resource. I use Reflector to do this.
3. You can extract the control template of a specific control using a tool. I use Expression Blend to do this. This also works for WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the XAML for native controls is not directly available as a file. You need to use a program for peeking into the WPF assemblies and extracting that info. I personally have used the [**Mole for Visual Studio**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/MoleForVisualStudioEdit.aspx) tool, which has done the job very well. It integrates as a debugger-visualiser, which is quite handy.

Comment: @Noldorin: I can see the style of a control if I implemented the style myself. But how do I get the default style for native controls? Mole doesn't show me that, I don't think. Please let me know if I am wrong. Thanks!!!

Comment: Mole is *designed* for showing you the styles of built-in (native) controls. The instructions should say all. What's the exact issue you're having?