# Get TreeView's styled expand/collapse icons

Tags: wpf

I need to render/draw the icons that the default TreeView uses for it's expand/collapse icons. I already found out that you can change them by writing a new style with x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle", but I have no idea how I could load that style from the currently loaded theme (e.g. Aero, Luna, etc.).
I already tried creating a ToggleButton and applying it's Style the StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle, but the resource can not be found:

```
<ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"></ToggleButton>
```

How can I apply styles defined in the default theme to controls they are not actually meant for?

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't really work that way.

you have to extract the styles from that specific theme, copy them to your code and then reference them. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662647/where-to-find-generic-xaml-for-native-wpf-controls) for how to extract the styles and templates. [Martin Liversage's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662647/where-to-find-generic-xaml-for-native-wpf-controls/1662718#1662718) number 2 doesn't only work on silverlight assemblies. You can use [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/) (too bad it's commercial now...) to get the styles and themes from wpf dlls too.

btw: the corresponding ddls are named like PresentationFramework.Luna.dll