# Tap transition effect when navigating to a page

Tags: xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8, effects, transition

In many built in apps as well as in some third party apps I can observe a nice effect that takes place when an item gets tapped thus causing page navigation. That tapped item swiftly slides over the screen before page transition happens (and slides back to it's original place when user goes back to a first page).

Here's a screenshot from mail app:
[image: Item slides once tapped]

I feel this is some kind of a generally accessible transition effect (maybe from WP Toolkit) rather than a custom work. If I'm right can someone please point out the name of this effect and how it can be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the transition name is "Continuum Transition", having that, I'm sure you will be able to find more information about it.

[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOr92Wqgn78) , that shows the transition effect

Hope this helps

Comment: Just to add to it +1 (even though I got beat to it lol), http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/04/04/metro-in-motion-3-flying-titles.html

Comment: True for the Continuum transition naming :) - I always used this example [http://benjii.me/2011/11/continuum-transition-for-windows-phone-silverlight-toolkit/](http://benjii.me/2011/11/continuum-transition-for-windows-phone-silverlight-toolkit/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a nice video that shows smooth transition like the wp7 menus

[Flip transition wp7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg232540.aspx)

and it requires Generic.xaml which can be found in

[Generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662647/where-to-find-generic-xaml-for-native-wpf-controls)

I guess generic.xaml might be available on the system also. Let me know if this is the animation you are looking to. Else please menton an App name to proceed further.

Comment: Thanks for video but it's not exactly what I want. Video talks about whole page transitions while I'm asking about tapped item transition. Try to tap any item in standard mail application in WP8 and you'll see that particular item sliding over the edge of the screen. That's what I'm interested in.

Comment: Ok here I found some use ful posts :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170308/windows-phone-7-navigation-animation && this codeplex project has a slide transition http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/345129/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions